# Angular 2 http.get call, Array length is 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a little trouble understanding why my array is empty, I have an ASP.Net api ctr that i call with an angular 2 service.
But for some reason the angular service result i empty? when i debug i can see that the API returns a list, of the type Card. So it is, not the api, that is not returning a result.

here is my typescript CardModel:

```
export class Card {
cardId: string;
name: string;
cardset: string;
type: string;
faction: string;
rarity: string;
cost: string;
attack: string;
health: string;
durability: string;
text: string;
inGameText: string;
flavor: string;
artist: string;
collectible: string;
elite: string;
race: string;
playerClass: string;
howToGet: string;
img: string;
imggold: string;
locale: string;
mechanics: string[];
```

}

And here is my angular 2 service, i can see when i debug that the service is called on Init so that is not the problem,

```
getCards(): Observable<Card[]> {


    return this.http.get(this.cardsUrl)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json().data as Card[])
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

}
```

and here is the component that calls the service,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCards();
}

loadCards() {
    return this.cardService.getCards()
        .subscribe(
        card => this.cards = card,
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

any of you know what the problem might be?

EDIT:
Here is where i want the data to be showen

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let card of cards">
        <td>{{card.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where are you using this array? (`this.cards`)

Comment: in a table i can post how i use it

Comment: Why are you using Angular 1 markup in an Angular 2 template?

Comment: *when i debug i can see that the API returns a list, of the type Card*: add a console.log() to your code, and add the printed result to your question, so that we can see that debugging information, too.

Comment: It's *ngFor, not *ng-for. Read the documentation. Read the (now deleted, but correct) answer you got. Carefully.

Comment: get the same error when i use ngFor, ng-for, and let or of. Same error..

Comment: Post the code that, according to your reading of the documentation, should be correct. Post the actual error you got when using that supposedly correct code. Don't try random things.

Comment: **Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly** - do read the error messages. Also, please run through an introductory Angular 2 tutorial rather than trying to guess what the markup might be.

Comment: Kevin it's not `*ng-for` it is `*ngFor`. Please read my answer and check the plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` is Angular1 syntax. In Angular2 use `ngFor` instead.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Hello World
  <tr *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <td>{{card?.name}}</td>
  </tr>`,
  directives: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AppComponent {
    private cards;
    constructor(){
      this.cards = [{name: 1},{name: 2},{name: 3}];
    }
}
```

Here's the full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pJWkLtiYonUpJfjZjCGd?p=preview

```
loadCards() {
    return this.cardService.getCards()
        .subscribe(
        (card) => {
          this.cards = card;
          console.log(this.cards); // Does this print undefined?
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: so now it complains over Can't bind to 'ng-forIn' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. Can you not call a repeater on a tr anymore?

Comment: `directives: [FormsModule]` is incorrect. And the import is useless, too.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I forgot that `ngFor` was a built-in directive.

Comment: It's not. As it's name indicates, FormsModule is a module, not a directive. The directives attribute of NgModule shouldn't be used anymore, and the plunkr doesn't use any form anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I've updated my answer and the plunker.

Comment: @echonax if i do like this i dont get an error any more, but for some reason the Card[] is still empty. Can it be because i send the result from the API Ctr as objects and not as json?

Comment: @KevinJensen what does `(card) => {this.cards = card; console.log(this.cards);},` print at the console?

Comment: it gives an undefined if i try and log there @echonax

Comment: @KevinJensen I've updated my answer to make it more clean. Does that print undefined?

Comment: If that prints undefined it means that you are not getting the data you need from the server. Or when you are doing `res.json().data` are you sure that the response have a `data` property?

Comment: @echonax im not sure? how can i check that?

Comment: @KevinJensen If you are using chrome, you can press F12 and check your xhr requests from the network tab.

Comment: it looks like the response i a string in json form.

Comment: @echonax it was because i called data after, thx for the help!

Comment: @KevinJensen glad you figured it out :)